# parse ansible fact variable with loop

Tags: ansible

I have below ansible playbook.

```yaml
- hosts: rhel
  tasks:
  - name: Get DNS
    setup:
      filter: ansible_dns
    register: dns
  - debug: var=dns
  - name: debug dns name
    debug:
      msg: "DNS ====> {{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ dns.ansible_facts }}"
```

Output I am getting

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inv get_facts.yaml

PLAY [rhel] ********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rhel8]

TASK [Get DNS] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rhel8]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rhel8] => {
    "dns": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "ansible_dns": {
                "nameservers": [
                    "172.31.0.2"
                ],
                "search": [
                    "ap-south-1.compute.internal"
                ]
            }
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}

TASK [debug dns details] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rhel8] => (item=ansible_dns) => {
    "msg": "DNS ====> ansible_dns"
}


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************
rhel8                      : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

In task 3, **debug dns name**, I am expecting output of complete DNS details, but I am only getting key names

```json
"ansible_dns": {
                "nameservers": [
                    "172.31.0.2"
                ],
                "search": [
                    "ap-south-1.compute.internal"
                ]
            }
```

It is given in [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html), we can parse ansible dictionary with keys. And its not working with ansible facts.

I have tried to parse like below too `{{ item | from_json | json_query('ansible_dns') }}`

but I am getting below error

```
TASK [debug dns details] *******************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [rhel8]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'msg': \"DNS ====> {{ item | from_json | json_query('ansible_dns') }}\"}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/vikram/mybooks/get_facts.yaml': line 7, column 15, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  - debug: var=dns\n              ^ here\n\nThere appears to be both 'k=v' shorthand syntax and YAML in this task. Only one syntax may be used.\n"}
```

Comment: what is the goal? or what is the desired output

Comment: @KevinC, I am expecting,, complete output not just a key. I had mentioned just below the playbook. Pls check.

Comment: @KevinC, how to parse variable in debug msg eg. `msg: "{{item.ansible_dns}}"`, bcz I am getting error while doing this. Not sure what I am violating, seems ok everything.

Comment: What is the expected output? Please add the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are registering the output of `setup` when it is not needed
2. You are running `setup` when it is not needed (since you did not disable fact gathering on the play, `setup` is called automatically and fully at start of play)
3. You are using an [`item` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/items_lookup.html) on a dict. So getting only key names is the expected result. From your description, I suspect you need a simple debug. But if you really want to loop on dict elements, you have to use a [`dict` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dict_lookup.html) or to use the [`dict2items` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dict2items_filter.html)

```yaml
- name: Get dns details
  hosts: rhel
  # Note: we don't use `gather_facts: false`
  # so no need to run `setup` explicitly

  tasks:
    - name: Show dns details in bulk
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: ansible_dns

    - name: Show dns details key by key
      # ... if this is what you are after.
      # Adapt to your exact need
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg:
          - "ansible_dns key is: {{ item.key }}"
          - "It contains value: {{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_dns | dict2items }}"
```

Note that the `loop:` line can be replaced by any of the below equivalent expression:

```yaml
      with_dict: "{{ ansible_dns }}"
      # or
      loop: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.dict', ansible_dns) }}"
```

Check [Ansible loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html) for more information.

---

Regarding the sentence:

> It is given in doc, we can parse ansible dictionary with keys. And its not working with ansible facts.

I don't get what the problem is exactly. As an example, here is a task to display the dns search domains

```yaml
    - name: Show dns search domains
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: ansible_dns.search
```

Note that the below would work to go over each key and get its value although using `dict2items` is much clea[r|n]er IMO (see above)

```yaml
    - name: Show value for each ansible_dns key
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: ansible_dns[item]
      with_items: "{{ ansible_dns }}"
```